# Why is my print statement not running below an else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
tries=int(input("Enter the number of times you wish to enter the password."))

password=[]

if tries == -1:
    while(True):
        password_guess=int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): "))
        password.append(password_guess)
        if password_guess == 999:
            print("correct password")
            break
        else:
            continue
else:
    #n=int(input("enter the amount of tries you want to have"))
    password=[0 for x in range(tries)]
    for i in range(tries):
        password[i]=int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): "))
        if 999 in password:
            print("correct password")
            break
        else:
            continue
            print("incorrect password")
            break
```

Just a beginner python learner. I am trying to make a password system where the user can input "tries" amount of times to enter a password, or type -1 for infinite tries. The password is 999. For example, let's say we enter 3 tries for the # of tries to enter a password. All of the guesses are wrong. However, instead of printing "incorrect password", nothing shows up on the screen. How do I fix this? Nothing else seems out of place besides the last "print" not showing up.

Comment: because of the *continue* before your *print* that *print* is never executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the *continue* before your *print* that *print* is never executed

*continue* asks to perform the next turn of the *for* (if compatible with end condition)

Note to have the expected behavior you must not only remove the *continue* in the *else* branch but also the *break*, so to have :

```
if 999 in password:
    print("correct password")
    break
else:
    print("incorrect password")
```

and because the *then* branch has a *break* you can also do :

```
if 999 in password:
    print("correct password")
    break
print("incorrect password")
```

Anyway to have :

```
password[i]=int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): "))
if 999 in password:
```

is strange because it is enough to have :

```
password[i]=int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): "))
if 999 == password[i]:
```

Your initialization :

> ```
> password=[0 for x in range(tries)]
> ```

is strange too because you can do `password=[]` and replace `password[i]=int(...` by `password.append(int(...` :

To have in your first *for*

> ```
> else:
>     continue
> ```

is also useless

So you can have :

```
tries=int(input("Enter the number of times you wish to enter the password."))

password=[]

if tries == -1:
    while(True):
        password_guess=int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): "))
        password.append(password_guess)
        if password_guess == 999:
            print("correct password")
            break
else:
    for i in range(tries):
        password.append(int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): ")))
        if 999 == password[i]:
            print("correct password")
            break
        else:
            print("incorrect password")

print("attempts : ", password)
```

Of course you can also use *password_guess* in both cases or none to have a similar code in both case, or to not write two times the same code using a function :

```
def enterPassword(password):
    password_guess=int(input("Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): "))
    password.append(password_guess)
    if password_guess == 999:
        print("correct password")
        return True
    else:
        print("incorrect password")
        return False


tries=int(input("Enter the number of times you wish to enter the password."))

password=[]

if tries == -1:
    while not enterPassword(password):
        pass
else:
    for i in range(tries):
        if enterPassword(password):
            break

print("attemps : ", password)
```

Executions supposing all in *p.py*:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 p.py
Enter the number of times you wish to enter the password.-1
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 1
incorrect password
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 2
incorrect password
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 999
correct password
attemps :  [1, 2, 999]
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 p.py
Enter the number of times you wish to enter the password.5
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 1
incorrect password
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 2
incorrect password
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 999
correct password
attemps :  [1, 2, 999]
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 p.py
Enter the number of times you wish to enter the password.2
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 1
incorrect password
Enter the password (hint: it is an integer): 2
incorrect password
attemps :  [1, 2]
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: @AbhinavMathur the *break* is not in the *else* part

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, this gives me "incorrect password" every time I enter a new password guess. How do I run through all wrong tries before the computer replies with "incorrect password"? Thank you for your help.